# DECRYPTBYKEYAUTOCERT in Azure Synapse

Tags: sql, azure-synapse

same question someone posted here https://app-pack.telkomuniversity.ac.id/re-azure-synapse-analytics-march-update-2022/

in Transact-SQL, there is method `DECRYPTBYKEYAUTOCERT` can use inside VIEW

in Synapse SQL, don't have this method, how to retrieve decrypted value from view (cannot use `OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY` inside view)

Answer (score 1):

**Unfortunately, DECRYPTBYKEYAUTOASYMKEY is not supported in Azure Synapse SQL Dedicated Pool.**

To decrypt a column in a view you must use DecryptByKeyAutoCert , DecryptByKeyAutoAsymKey, or DecryptByPassphrase none of which is available in Synapse SQL Pool and it only supported in SQL Server.

Appreciate if you could share the feedback on our [Azure Synapse feedback channel](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/forum/9b9ba8e4-0825-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f07b8) which is open for the user community to upvote & comment on. This allows our product teams to effectively prioritize your request against our existing feature backlog and gives insight into the potential impact of implementing the suggested feature.